# When running a simple Jenkins pipeline I am running into A DOCKER-ENPOINT error

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, endpoint

I am creating a simple Jenkins pipeline and run into the error below:

```
Started by user XYZ
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/XYZ1
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix (hide)
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . ubuntu:latest
unable to resolve docker endpoint: open C:/Program Files/Git/certs/client/ca.pem: no such file or directory
```

My pipeline is as such:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'ubuntu:latest' }
   }
   environment {
       dockerImage =''
       registry = 'https://github.com/XYZS/XYZ'
       registryCredential ='d34d387c-0abe-4e39-9260-588e5ad529aa'
   }
  stages {
    stage("Set Up") {
      steps {
        git branch: 'main', url: 'https://github.com/XYZS/XYZ'
      }
    }
    stage("Build docker image") {
      steps {
        script {
            dockerImage = docker.build registry
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Push image') {
     steps {
        script {
            docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'git') {
            app.push("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
            app.push("latest")
            }
        }
      }
    }
     stage ('Push to Docker') {
        steps {
            script {
               docker.withRegistry( '', registryCredential ) {
                dockerImage.push()
               }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

As of yet I have as advised on other forums to delete and re-install Docker, however, the certs folder in the Git directory does not actually exist.

Has anyone come across this problem and how did you resolve it?

Many thanks in advance,